# Pass server-side data into Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm currently trying to display the name of the logged-in user in my MEAN app. I'm using the EJS templating engine and I'm able to get the username showing by putting `<%- user.username %>` in my markup. The problem with this is that I don't really want to my mixing angular and embedded scripts in the same files, I'd like to pass the server-side data into Angular. I've tried ng-init but I'm not having any success at all with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are using ExpressJS 4 it will be a little different in version 3, however the approach will be the same for both versions:

**Node/Sever side**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var schema = require("./schemas");
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();

router.get('api/account', function(req, res){
  res.json({ "login": req.session.user.login }); /*access the session account not sure if this matches your login location you will adapt it to your own*/
});
```

**Angular/Client Side**

You then invoke from your controller or service the url `api/account` with a GET request to receive the JSON  like:

```
$http.get("/api/account").then(function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

then you could do something like:

```
$scope.login = data.login;
```

and in the `html`

```
{{login}}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Is there any particular reason why in order to call the login I have to pass in data twice? ie. $scope.username = data.data.login.username

Comment: That's because the `data` in the callback is actually an object with multiple properties such as `headers`, `status`, and `data`. So I think the code in the answer should be adjusted.

Comment: @Dalorzo I am. Have you tested this? Looks like when you use the `success` or `error` method it's as you say, but with the `then` method it's different. From the section called Returns:

"The arguments passed into these functions are destructured representation of the response object passed into the then method. The response object has these properties:

data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions..."

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of Angular, it discourages server-side setting of templated values in HTML code. Consider setting up a JSON service that provides the data, and fetching the data over JSON. There is an example [at the end of the Angular Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) that may make this clearer.

Comment: Actually I think I have found the problem. When I return 'user' it fetches the whole user object from the database and with it is _id: which is generated by mongoose and it contains illegal characters, ` _id: 5380c1b57cb76dcc0f647524,` - this is now a separate issue but is there a way to format _id?

Answer (score 0):

I do the exact same thing and mix EJS to embed things like my server info (to initiate a socket connection from the client). If you wanted to keep this purely client-side, you would need to have AngularJS fetch the server-side data using a service / factory - and then affect any views you have depending on said data.

[ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) only applies to things which live inside the "Angular" scope.